# CPU and Memory Utilization from F5 Device ( ADC Load Balancer ) - Node (Server) wise

Tags: networking, memory, cpu-usage, snmp, f5

Can somebody help me out to retrieve the CPU and Memory utilization details for the list of nodes available in the F5 inventory using SNMP ( from F5 )

Comment: Can I have the reason for downvoting ?

Comment: Dear Downvoters, can you pl specify the reason behind ?

Comment: I think you are voted down because this would seem to be a network question for [sf], not a programming question for [so].

Comment: @Ron Maupin, thanks for update

Comment: Poke around support.f5.com for your MIB answers. They have a lot of resources around MIB use and you should be able to get what you need there without being downvoted.  https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/bigip-external-monitoring-implementations-11-3-0/8.html

Comment: downvote because the question shows no effort of reading the doc

Comment: @ Eugène Adell, Thanks for downvoting, It is not there the docs, If it is there can you post the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The F5-3DNS-MIB indeed has MIB objects hostCPU and hostMemory that have the instrumentation you want. What F5 products this is implemented in only F5 would know. Time for their "Technical Support"?

Comment: Is it per Node. ( not the F5 Box's cpu and memory ) ?

Comment: Is  'F5-3DNS-MIB' provides per Node / Server configured under the pool ? This seems to be for the F5 Box itself...